New internal Hitachi HDD corrupted/damaged after being installed in a audio car system
My brother owns a Dodge Journey from 2010, whose uConnect system (radio, 40 GB internal HDD and rear camera) began to freeze or shutdown almost in a random basis. We disassembled it to try to find some defective cables and/or loose connectors but we found nothing unusual. Since a lot of times the freezes happened when listening to music from the HDD, I removed the internal HDD to see if that was the culprit and yes, as soon as I removed it, the problem went away. The system as a whole has been 100% steady.
I used an IDE to USB adapter to connect the HDD to my PC just to see if it was working or not. The unit for sure got energized and I was able to hear the discs spinning, but Windows Explorer never showed any partition. I didn't investigate further and just bought a new unit (the same model: HITACHI HEJ421040G9AT00).
As soon as the new HDD arrived I connected it to my PC to check that the drive was working and I was able to see three partitions already created with some pre-installed data with navigation icons and some language packs. Then we connected the new HDD to the car and when we turned the car on, the system showed nothing, like if the HDD wasn't plugged.
I removed it from the car and connected it again to my PC to delete all the partitions and create a single 40 GB one (thinking that maybe the three partitions and the pre-installed data was messing with the car's system), but that's when I found out the new HDD behaving exactly as the original one: it got energized, you can hear it spinning but Windows Explorer showed nothing.
This time I opened Disk Management and the HDD appeared there but as "Not Initialized". When I tried the "Initialize Disk" option (I tried both MBR and GPT), after a couple of seconds I got a message stating that the request cannot be performed due to an I/O error.
I tried updating the controllers and the problem persists.
Finally, I checked the old HDD in Disk Management too, and as the new one, it appeared as "Not Initialized" and when I tried to fix it, I got the same I/O error.
I'm assuming something in the car system is corrupting the HDD or some electrical issue is damaging part of the motherboard.
I'd appreciate if anyone can point me out if there is anything that can be done to fix the issue or maybe it's better to forget about it and update the whole uConnect system with a new modern one?

Update for clarification: The car's system has an option to show some info about the internal HDD: Total Capacity, Used Capacity and Total amount of files in the HDD. When the original HDD was removed, all those fields show a dash symbol (-) which to me indicates: there's nothing to show cause there's no disk plugged.
After installing the new HDD, I was expecting to see at the least the first field (total capacity) showing either the HDD's capacity (40 GB) or the capacity of one of the three partitions (10 GB, 10 GB, 20 GB. All of them were FAT32) but instead I continued to get the dash symbol in all the fields.

The HDD doesn't have to be defect. By writing something to the disk where Windows expects the partition table you can confuse Windows. Usually such disks can be "recovered" by erasing the first sectors on disk e.g. using dd on Linux or on Windows you can even use a hex editor like HxD and open the raw disk.

You might need to contact Dodge and ask them.  There may be something you need to do to get it work in the truck, as it might be something proprietary.

The car's system might have formatted the disk with a filesystem that is not supported by Windows. Try if a Linux system can use the disk(s). What do you expect to see in the car's system when the (empty) harddisk is connected?

Thanks to all for your input. @bodo: The car's system has an option to show info about the HDD, as far as I can remember: total capacity, used capacity and number of files. When the HDD wasn't plugged, each field showed a "-". After connecting the new one I was expecting to show at least the 40 Gb or at least one of the three partitions (10 Gb, 10 Gb, 20 Gb) but it continued to show a dash symbol "-", that's why I said in my original post that the system acted like no disk was connected. I'm ignorant about Linux, but I'll try to look for a distro that can run from a thumb drive or a CD.

You should [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question. (Without your explanation it was not clear if the system would distinguish between no disk and empty disk.)

maybe trying something newer https://www.amazon.com/Transcend-PSD330-2-5-inch-Internal-Solid/dp/B00AQT2LCU/

Likely, the two HDD's can be saved, and formatted, at least for use on a PC.

Attach the HDD, but do not attempt to examine it in Explorer, or otherwise mount it..
Open diskmgmt.msc, or use a third-party tool such as DiskGenius.
Select each partition and delete it. Confirm the action (or "save") for each partition -- most disk management tools require a second step for such an action.
The whole drive should be free space.
Now create one (or more) partition.
Format the partition as desired, such as FAT32 or NTFS for general use. [The Dodge might require a different format, such as ext4 for Linux or Android.]
As soon as it's formatted, Windows should recognize and mount the drive.


I tried DiskGenius on both HDDs and the results were identical: Both HDDs have all the sectors damaged; by all, I mean the 100% of them, not a single one not damaged. When I try to repair them, I get the same I/O error for every sector it tries to fix (error 1117 according to DiskGenius).
